# In the following code, why does useEffect care if a variable is null?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

In the following code, a variable is initially set to null because it does not currently exist in local storage. Yet useEffect complains that `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'null')` and points to the `isDeclared` variable in its dependency. Why is useEffect rejecting a variable with a value of null? I would just like it to set the value of the `isDeclared` key in the local storage to `null` on the first render. Thanks!

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function ClassSearch() {
  const [isDeclared, setIsDeclared] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("isDeclared")
  );
  const [major, setMajor] = useState(localStorage.getItem("major"));

  useEffect((isDeclared) => {
    return localStorage.setItem("isDeclared", isDeclared);
  })[isDeclared];

  useEffect((major) => {
    return localStorage.setItem("major", major);
  })[major];

  return <div>{`This isn\'t operational yet`}</div>;
}

export default ClassSearch;
```

Comment: I'd recommend a read through the official [Effect Hook documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). The return statement inside a `useEffect` is used for the cleanup phase of the effect. You're also using the dependencies array incorrectly.

Comment: The syntax is `useEffect(cb, [dep]);`, not `useEffect(cb)[dep];`

Answer (score 2):

It's Syntax error in your code,
Incorrect return in useEffect, and use of dependency,

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function ClassSearch() {
  const [isDeclared, setIsDeclared] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("isDeclared")
  );
  const [major, setMajor] = useState(localStorage.getItem("major"));

  useEffect(
    (isDeclared) => {
      console.log(1);
      localStorage.setItem("isDeclared", isDeclared);
    },
    [isDeclared]
  );

  useEffect(
    (major) => {
      console.log(1);
      localStorage.setItem("major", major);
    },
    [major]
  );

  return <div>{`This isn't operational yet`}</div>;
}

export default ClassSearch;
```